# C# Linq Order a list with a reference list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists and I need to sort a list with another list.

```
var orderList = new List<long>() {4, 55, 34};
var itemList = new List<Branch>() { {Id=55, Name="X"},  {Id=34, Name="Y"}, {Id=4, Name="Z"} };
```

How can I order second list namely `itemList` according to first one `orderList` ?

Is there any linq short way?

**Update:**

`orderList` will always have all expected `Id` branch contained `itemList`.

Comment: What should happen to items from `itemList` that doesn't exist in `orderList` ? How should they be ordered in this scenario?

Comment: @Fabjan, there is not such a case in my problem. I get itemList according to orderList. If you have a solution to get itemList ordered by orderList then it is also accepted

Comment: @Fabjan I didn't see the comment of the OP so I updated his question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `LINQ` and order the items by their index in other array:

```
var orderedItemList = itemList.OrderBy(x => orderList.IndexOf(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

you can perform below linq to solve your issue:

```
 List<Branch> sortedProducts = new List<Branch>();

 orderList.ForEach(x => sortedProducts.Add(itemList.FirstOrDefault(ele => ele.Id == x)));
```

Note:- here only those element will be added whose index is present in the `orderList`.

Comment: Thanks for marking as duplicated. I couldn't find it, you did.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
itemList = itemList.OrderBy(d => orderList.IndexOf(d.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can order by the index of the `Id` in the `orderList`:

```
var result = itemList.OrderBy(e => orderList.IndexOf(e.Id)).ToList();
```