# Sorting a collection containing strings and/or numbers

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of **100** elements, which are looking something like that:

1. dog
2. cat (2)
3. bird (34)
4. cat + dog (11)
5. dog (5)

Additionally I have a specific required order, lets say:

```
string[] order = {"dog", "bird", "cat", "cat + dog"};
```

I need my method to sort by aforementioned order and then by numbers, to get as a result:

1. dog
2. dog (5)
3. bird (34)
4. cat (2)
5. cat + dog (11)

Currently i have something like that:

```
bool equal = collection
  .OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(order, i.Split('(').First()))
  .ThenBy(i => i.Split('(').Last().Replace(")", " "))
  .SequenceEqual(collection2);
```

But it doesn't work. `ThenBy` overlaps first sorting.
Also upon entering `int.Parse` to the `ThenBy` brackets i'm getting an *exception*.

Help me to achieve this.

Comment: Are you planning to make a custom compare function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alphanumeric sorting using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq)

Comment: *"list of 100 elements"* is the element literally the string "cat (2)" or is that an element with properties `cat` and `2`

Comment: Does parsing your i.Split('(').Last().Replace(")", " ") into a number help? i.e. bool equal = collection
  .OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(order, i.Split('(').First()))
  .ThenBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split('(').Last().Replace(")", " ")))
  .SequenceEqual(collection2);

Comment: @Lucifer He has another step: ordering an array by another array

Comment: @Jamiec yes, it's literally a string

Comment: @asidis I am getting an exception "Invalid input string format" and i have no idea why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812105/c-sharp-linq-order-a-list-with-a-reference-list/50812288#50812288 ??

Comment: @asidis Use this one: `new Regex(@"^(?<name>.*?)( \((?<number>[0-9]+)\))?$")`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting initial lines into anonymous class instances: having this done (and debugged) you can put just

```
.OrderBy(item => Array.IndexOf(order, item.name))
.ThenBy(item => item.count)
```

Implementation:

```
  List<string> collection = new List<string> {
    "dog",
    "cat (2)",
    "bird (34)",
    "cat + dog (11)",
    "dog (5)",
  };

  string[] order = { "dog", "bird", "cat", "cat + dog" };

  var result = collection
    .Select(item => item.Split('('))
    .Select(parts => parts.Length == 1 // do we have "(x)" part?
       ? new { name = parts[0].Trim(), count = 1 } // no
       : new { name = parts[0].Trim(), count = int.Parse(parts[1].Trim(')')) }) // yes
    .OrderBy(item => Array.IndexOf(order, item.name)) // now it's easy to work with data
    .ThenBy(item => item.count)
    .Select(item => item.count == 1 // back to the required format
       ? $"{item.name}"
       : $"{item.name} ({item.count})")
    .ToList();

 Console.WriteLine( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
dog
dog (5)
bird (34)
cat (2)
cat + dog (11)
```

**Edit**: your code amended `Trim()` added within `OrderBy`; `ThenBy` redesigned

```
  var result = collection
    .OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(order, i.Split('(').First().Trim())) // Trim
    .ThenBy(i => i.Contains('(')                                     // two cases:
       ? int.Parse(i.Split('(').Last().Replace(")", ""))             // with "(x)" part
       : 1)                                                          // without
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite the same answer than [@Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) using regex:

```
var collection = new List<string> {
    "dog",
    "cat (2)",
    "bird (34)",
    "cat + dog (11)",
    "dog (5)",
};

string[] order = { "dog", "bird", "cat", "cat + dog" };

var regex = new Regex("^(?<name>.*?)\\s*(\\((?<number>[0-9]+)\\))?$");

var result = collection
  .Select(i =>
    {
      var match = regex.Match(i);
      return new {
          content = i,
          name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
          number = int.TryParse(match.Groups["number"].Value, out int number) 
            ? number 
            : 1 };
    })
  .OrderBy(item => Array.IndexOf(order, item.name))
  .ThenBy(item => item.number)
  .Select(i => i.content)
  .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You can add `\s*` into pattern `var regex = new Regex(@"(?<name>.*)\s*\\((?<number>[0-9]+)\\)");` and get rid of `Trim()`: `.OrderBy(item => Array.IndexOf(order, item.name))`

Comment: Since `default(int) == 0` I doubt that it should be used; probably it should be `1`: `... ? number : 1` - if quantity - `(number)` - is omitted then *one* animal mentioned: `"dog"` - one dog, `"dog (5)"` - five dogs.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are right, it will make the code better ;-) I've also added a non greedy expression for the name or it will keep the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

No checks done... The data is perfect or everything goes boom:

```
var res = (from x in collection
           let ix = x.LastIndexOf(" (")
           orderby Array.IndexOf(order, ix != -1 ? x.Remove(ix) : x),
               ix != -1 ? int.Parse(x.Substring(ix + 2, x.Length - 1 - (ix + 2))) : 0
           select x).ToArray();
```

Note the dual handling of `ix != -1`. In the second line of the `orderby` (that is the `ThenBy()` in functional LINQ), if `ix == -1` then the value is `: 0`)